# Issue with compilation of rdenoise for GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-grass-plugin

I would like to use r.denoise an external tool of GRASS.
So I tried to install it following instructions from this page [r.denoise manual](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/addons/r.denoise.html)
But the terminal returns me an error during compilation:

> mdenoise.cpp: In function ‘void ReadXYZ(FILE*)’: mdenoise.cpp:1418:21:
> warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’
> [-Wwrite-strings]  1418 |
> triangulate("zqBQ",&in,&out,&vorout); mdenoise.cpp:1420:21: warning:
> ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’
> [-Wwrite-strings]  1420 |         triangulate("zBQ",&in,&out,&vorout);

I don't know how to solve it, i have no knowledge in c++ and compilation.
Somebody can help me ?

Comment: I think those messages are only warnings. Did you try to add the r.denoise extension after you compiled mdenoise? (Note in the manual page that you have to add a link to the mdenoise executable somewhere on your path)

Comment: @Micha Next command is `ln -s pwd/mdenoise /some/directory/on/the/$PATH` But what is the path I have to put ?

Comment: You need to link the full path of the mdenoise executable to somewhere on your $PATH. If you are on a Linux or Mac system, then typically the directory `"/home/<your username>/bin` will be in the $PATH. So create a softlink in that directory to the mdenoise executable. HTH